# Old sf film: spaceship has detachable drill nose cone

Tags: story-identification

This has been haunting me for mostly all my life, a film I saw as a child during the 70s. Can't tell if it was theater or TV.
 I basically only remember the last scene of the film:

There is some form of deadlock between a human spaceship and another hostile one (aliens, other humans?). This spaceship has some form of drill as nose cone; which is detachable but has to have someone ride it.

> Spoiler The deadlock is solved by some hero climbing into the drill pod and riding it into the hostile ship. I seem to recall his daughter was also on board and tries to dissuade him.

**Edit**(per comments) I'm almost sure it was a live action film.

Comment: Was the film live action? Do you remember any of the actors, or where the film was set? Even the character or location names might help.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 Good point, added as edit. Thanks!

Comment: Which language was the film in?

Comment: @maguirenumber6: I surely saw it in Spanish, but that's no real info as in Spain everything is dubbed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's "The War in Space"? A 70's japanese Sci-Fi movie.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_in_Space)